# How to separate out/ return values not present in DB table using sqlalchmey in python project?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In my python project, I am querying DB table using filter and my filter is a list with multiple values. As it is a list data type, I am using _in operator in my sqlalchmey query. Now my use case is to separate out values in my filters if they are present in my table and also if they are not present in table.

For example:

filter = [95, 100]

Using above filter I will query a particular attribute of my table (lets say "id").And I am using "_in" operator. Suppose id= 100 is not present in table , I should return "record with id=100 not found" and also the fetched data for id= 95. Can somebody help with the problem? Thanks in advance.

Right now I could achieve fetching and returning data for filter values that are present. Butwas not able to return the record not found message for absent filter value. As explained above , need to get output for both present and absent values.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve information about values with both do and do not have matches in the database you could create a temporary table from the values that you are querying and then do a left outer join against the model.  This will return tuples of `(value, object)`, and `object` will be `None` if there is no match.

For example. say we have a `User` model and we want to query against its `name` attribute.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# These are the names that we want to query.
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Yolanda', 'Zack']

with Session() as s:
    # Create a temporary table. metadata should be the metadata
    # object that contains the model (probably Base.metadata).
    temp_table = sa.Table(
        't74223060tmp', metadata, sa.Column('name', sa.String)
    )
    temp_table.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
    temp_table.create(engine)

    # Insert the names (but don't commit).
    s.execute(temp_table.insert(), [{'name': name} for name in names])

    # Define the query.
    q = (
        s.query(temp_table.c.name, User)
        .join(User, temp_table.c.name == User.name, isouter=True)
    )
    print()
    for row in q:
        print(row)
    print()

    # Rollback or dropping the table may hang the session
    s.rollback()
    temp_table.drop(engine)
```

Sample output:

```
('Alice', <__main__.User object at 0x7f0035f7f2d0>)
('Bob', <__main__.User object at 0x7f0035f7f390>)
('Yolanda', None)
('Zack', None)
```

Comment: This is a great solution. But unfortunately in my particular case there are many records to be dealt with. Any thoughts with that? But thank you very much.

Comment: What database are you targetting?

Comment: Targeting Oracle db.

Comment: @Rdeveloper reworked to show one way to do it on the database side.